# OpsCenter 6.1.2 keeps crashing after update from 6.0.X "No agents available to query for getDsePerformanceStatusFromOneAgent"

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

After updating OpsCenter 6.0.X to 6.1.2 using yum, OpsCenter frequently crashes with the following error in opsenterd.log:

```
2017-08-25 10:03:34,066 [opscenterd] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred: No agents available to query for getDsePerformanceStatusFromOneAgent.
File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1124, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "/usr/share/opscenter/jython/Lib/site-packages/opscenterd/Cluster.py", line 1301, in callOnAgent
```

(MainThread)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This indicates that there is an agent issue. Please check the DataStax Agent logs to see if there are any errors. You can try restarting them in the meantime.

Comment: Could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by updating the run directory file /etc/opscenter/clusters/< clustername >.conf
with

```
[agent_config] 
tmp_dir = /path/to/agent/tmp
```

But this is a temporary solution.